# Create a new Erc20 contract through Ether.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I've a functionality in my nextJs application to create an ERC20 token on a fly. Like user can input a contract name and symbol, and behind the scene through the Ether.js a new contract gets created and deployed. I've searched all around but couldn't find any such example. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const contractAbi = [...]; // ABI of your ERC-20 contract
const contractBytecode = '0x...'; // Compiled bytecode of your ERC-20 contract
const providerUrl = 'https://your-infura-url-here.com'; // Ethereum provider URL

async function deployTokenContract(name, symbol, initialSupply, privateKey) {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(providerUrl);
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

    const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(contractAbi, contractBytecode, wallet);

    const contract = await factory.deploy(name, symbol, initialSupply);
    await contract.deployed();

    return contract;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mehran Ra's code doesn't seem to work in my case. Specifically you the provider line didn't work for me. Adjusted the code would look like this:

```js
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const contractAbi = [...]; // ABI of your ERC-20 contract
const contractBytecode = '0x...'; // Compiled bytecode of your ERC-20 contract
const providerUrl = 'https://your-infura-url-here.com'; // Ethereum provider URL

async function deployTokenContract(name, symbol, initialSupply, privateKey) {
    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(providerUrl);
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

    const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(contractAbi, contractBytecode, wallet);

    const contract = await factory.deploy(name, symbol, initialSupply);
    await contract.deployed();

    return contract;
}
```